# Pixel-wise Image manipulation in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, image-processing

Suppose I have two large images (potentially 4096 x 4096 pixels each), image1 and image2.

What is the most efficient method to combine these two images with a custom combine function:

```
output.r = func_r(image1.r, image2.r)
output.g = func_g(image1.g, image2.g)
output.b = func_b(image1.b, image2.b)
```

Comment: What are you using to handle the image? JS/node is not the most efficient for manipulating image data, so if you're using it then you shouldn't worry too much about efficiency. Just adding the r/g/b values should work

Comment: We are using a node-canvas based implementation. However, it is taking up too much memory and setting the image into the canvas seems to need a base64 conversion of the image (again more memory).

We are not so much concerned about processor efficiency (though that would be nice to have) as we are about memory efficiency.